# how to make a field read only for all users except admin in django

Tags: python

i need to make Assign_manager field readonly for all users except for admin because he is the one who is assigning.
my models.py

```
class Manager(models.Model):
  Manager_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  Manager_id =  models.IntegerField(default=0,primary_key=True)
  Email_id = models.EmailField(max_length=20,blank=True)
  def __unicode__(self):
      return unicode(self.Manager_id)` class Manager(models.Model):



class Request(models.Model):

  discussion_points = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  Request_id =  models.IntegerField(default=0,primary_key=True)
  companies = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  industry = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  Functional_area= models.CharField(max_length=200)
  Budget = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  status = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='d')
  Assign_manager =models.ForeignKey(Manager,blank=True,null=True)
  Assign_executive= models.ForeignKey(Executive,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='none',blank=True)
  Rateperhour=models.IntegerField(blank=True,default=5,null=True)
  linkedin_url = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

Comment: There are lots of different ways so this is too broad.

Comment: suggest me one way